# Status of two Banach space theory open problems posted by Pełczyński

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-problems

In the book ['Open Problems in the Geometry and Analysis of Banach Spaces'](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319335711), I am interested in the following two problems.

> **Problem $1$**: Let $X$ be a separable infinite-dimensional Banach space that is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space.
>
> (i) (A. Pełczyński) Does there exist an infinite dimensional subspace of $X$ with Schauder basis that is not complemented in $X?$
>
> (ii) (A. Pełczyński) Do there exist two infinite-dimensional subspaces of $X$ with Schauder basis that are not isomorphic?

I would like to know status of the two problems above.
Are they solved or still open?

Comment: I believe these are open (and I think they are equivalent to each other). However, if you relax the assumption a bit as `every subspace is isomorphic to a complemented subspace', then there are non-Hilbertian examples. These were constructed by Johnson-Szankowski http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bill.johnson/HAP5.2.4.pdf

Comment: @BunyaminSari: Thanks. If possible, can you provide a reference showing that the two questions are equivalent?

Comment: I think that it is even open whether $X$ must be isomorphic to a Hilbert space if every subspace of $X$ with a Schauder basis is complemented and isomorphic to a Hilbert space.